# regex for creating pritty urls in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

What is the right regex to

create this url: domain.nl/projecten/scheidingswanden from

```
http://www.domain.nl/?module=projectencat&action=scheidingswanden
```

**in other words: replace the variable names ?module= and &action= with slashes**

**but also the other way around
because the frontcontroller needs to read the get variables module and action**

I don't know if it's only htaccess, but this logic is missing

thanks, Richard

Comment: So your users use URLs with slashes and you would like to rewrite that to ?module.. Or is it the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)/index.html$ index.php?module=projectencat&action=scheidingswanden

[a-zA-Z]+ = requires one or more alphabetic chars
(.*)      = requires one or more any kind of chars
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/])/([^/])$    ?module=projectencat&action=scheidingswanden  [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$    ?module=$1&action=$2
```

Comment: Well you URL has projecten and the query param is projectencat.. Didn't know what to do with that.. I'll remove it as it is probably not what you want..