# Simple PHP Routing Project

Tags: php, url-routing

I need to create a simple routing mechanism that takes a request like: /foo/bar and translates it to FooController->barAction(); I have to use a single script as an access point to load these controller classes and action methods. I also cannot use any external frameworks or libraries to accomplish this task. This needs to be able to be run on a PHP 5.3 Server with Apache.

Below is what I've written already, but I'm having trouble getting it to work:

```
class Router {

    private static $routes = array();

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}

    public static function route($pattern, $callback) {
        $pattern = '/' . str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern) . '/';
        self::$routes[$pattern] = $callback;
    }

    public static function execute() {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $base = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
        if (strpos($url, $base) === 0) {
            $url = substr($url, strlen($base));
        }
        foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $callback) {
            if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $params)) {
                array_shift($params);
                return call_user_func_array($callback, array_values($params));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to at least execute my current script which is based off another simple Router, but I cannot actually get an output using

```
Router::route('blog/(\w+)/(\d+)', function($category, $id){
  print $category . ':' . $id;
});
Router::execute();
```

Comment: You have given us a long list with requirements and a wall of code, but forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I'd look at existing projects. Random example: http://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router

Comment: " I also cannot use any external frameworks or libraries to accomplish this task." but noone forbids you to look at their source code. Using a library is not just shoving a black box into an application. And code analysis is what makes a programmer a good one.

Comment: I just need someone to look at my code and some guidance on what would be the next step. I know how to do standard URL rewrites with .htaccess, but I need to be able to translate the URI request to FooController->barAction();

Comment: I just updated what I am using to at least execute the class (which is based off another simple router, but I can't actually get an output or my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to break out the PATH.  Why not use .htaccess instead.

So you could have internal URL's that look like this:

```
index.php?module=MODULE&action=INDEX
```

Then use .htaccess to provide the paths in the URL and the route them accordingly.

```
www.mydomain.com/MODULE/INDEX
```

This post can help with the rewriting [regex for creating pritty urls in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007422/regex-for-creating-pritty-urls-in-htaccess)

There might be a better one, was just a quick google search.

This way you can access like this:

```
$module = $_GET['module'];
$action = $_GET['action];
```

Then you can do checks to corresponding actions in your router to check if it exists and then re-route accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would translate the URI request though to FooController->barAction();. Normally I would just be using regex with .htaccess to make pretty URLs or do redirects.

Comment: This solution isn't very flexible. I.e. what if you want to have deeper URLs at some point. Or you want to break with the above convention for whatever reason (e.g. deeplinks)?

Comment: @PeeHaa You add more to it, this was just an example to get him thinking towards his solution, to make it easier and not dependent on parsing the path with regex.  This is how most frameworks do it...